# How to save array in list by value not reference in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want to save my current state of array and later change that array but when I save my array in list and then change my array, array in list also changes. This is a sample code and a part of my code :

```
void main()
{
    List<int[]> lisarr = new List<int[]>();
    int[] a = new int[1];
    a[0] = 1;
    lisarr.Add(a);
    a[0] = 10;
    // at this time lisarr[0] also changes
   ....
}
```

If you trace this code notice that my array in list also change, but I don't want this. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a copy of your array:

```
List<int[]> lisarr = new List<int[]>();
int[] a = new int[1];
a[0] = 1;
lisarr.Add(a.ToArray());
a[0] = 10;
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this works because `ToArray()` internally copies all of its elements to a new array using `Array.CopyTo()` and then returns it.